# AJAX with JSONP returns error Callback is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax call. I know the headers are correct because when I access the url directly it gives me something like this: `jsonpCallback({"id":"274"})`

But when I make the ajax call - it is saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonpCallback is not defined`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/product/rest/company?' + $('form').serialize(),
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true, // enable this
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

What am I doing wrong in this call?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CORS, you are using JSONP.

Comment: `crossDomain: true, // enable this` — That does nothing. You are using JSONP (and it is almost always pointless when you aren't).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks - I'll change the title. And remove crossDomain. Do you know why ajax is not recognizing my callback name though?

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Your suggestion worked.

Comment: Because large portions of it were wrong and I didn't have the energy to fix them.

Comment: Okay - well the right part which I was missing which solved the problem was that the attribute in ajax to define the callback name required is `jsonpCallback` so I just did `jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback"` and it worked. So if you want to put that part down, I'll mark it as solved :-)

Comment: That's a terrible solution which leads to race conditions. It's the bit of the answer marked "Don't do this". I really don't want to make an answer which consists solely of that.

Comment: @itamar Hi, I took some time to suggest two quick-fix to your bug as well as a better approach to JSONP. I would be glad if you could take a look at my answer and evaluate if it can considered correct [ and flagged accordingly :-) ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The server is giving back the JSONP resource using the **wrong** callback function name.

You wrote that the response from the server is something like:

`jsonpCallback({"id":"274"})`

The JSON data is wrapped into the padding function `jsonpCallback` whose name is not matching with the parameter specified in the Ajax request. It should be:

`callback({"id":"274"})`

in fact `callback` is the name passed as `jsonpCallback` option in the jQuery AJAX call

`jsonpCallback: 'callback',`

Editing the server side script that generates the response to apply a proper callback name will fix things.

Alternatively you can fix things on "the other side" by making the ajax call parameter matching with the function name in the response:

`jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',`

---

The above is the "quick fix".

**However it is strongly reccomended that you don't specify a custom callback name** (using the parameter `jsonpCallback`).

Instead let jQuery generate a random callback name for each request.

The server side script will then parse the GET parameter `callback` and use the name passed for the callback function name that wraps the JSON data.

For example if you make a request like:

`http://localhost:9000/product/rest/company?param=123`

jQuery will add a parameter to the query string like this:

`http://localhost:9000/product/rest/company?param=123&callback=jQuery1520422276`

(it actually uses a longer callback name)

The server should parse `callback` and build up the response using the value passed as the padding function that wraps the JSON returned data:

`jQuery1520422276({"id":"274"})`